# Index a Treemap value in java

Tags: java, indexing, treemap

I have a Treemap in  pairs and need to find a specific value, locate its position (index) and do some calculations. The for loop did find the specific value, but it loops repeatedly based on System.out.println outputs. Is there any way just to return myValue once the if statement satisfies without continuing looping?

```
                   double myValue;

                   for (Map.Entry<Double, String> entry : treeMap1.entrySet()) {
                             double key = entry.getKey();
             String value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", key, value);
                            System.out.println("Current value is: " + value);

                  //Locate specific values
              for (int pos=0; pos<treeMap1.size(); pos++) {

                 if (value.contains("abc")) 
                  { myValue = (double) 1/pos+1;
                   System.out.println("Current value is: " + value);
                   System.out.println("Current pos value is: " + pos);
                   System.out.println("Current my value is: " + myValue);}

         } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply come out of the for loop using `break` keyword once condition is met:

```
    for (int pos=0; pos<treeMap1.size(); pos++) {

             if (value.contains("abc")) 
              { myValue = (double) 1/pos+1;
               System.out.println("Current value is: " + value);
               System.out.println("Current pos value is: " + pos);
               System.out.println("Current my value is: " + myValue);
               break; // break the for loop
              }

     }
```

Comment: It stops the loop, but myValue becomes infinity. Do I need to specify Array[pos] instead?

Comment: I don't think you need two loops, second loop is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips. The following is a revised Java class and it's now working!

```
   import java.util.Map;

      public class MyValueCalculate {
      public static double mrr (Map<Double, String> map, String relSent) {
           int pos=0;
           double myValue = 0.0;
           for (Map.Entry<Double, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            pos = pos + 1;
            String value = entry.getValue();
           //System.out.println("Current value is: " + value);

      if (value.contains(relSent)) {
         myValue = (double) 1/pos;
         System.out.println("Current pos value is: " + pos);
         System.out.println("Current myValue is: " + myValue);
         break;
         } }
         return myValue;
         } }
```